# Can you recover a wallet with only BIP39 seed or BIP32 root key?

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

Can we access and withdraw BTC if we have bip32 seed and bip32 root key? But we don't have the bip39 passphrase

[image: Ian Coleman utility]

Comment: Was the wallet created using a bip39 passphrase? If it was, you'll need it. If it wasn't, then you won't.

Comment: No I mean if someone get my bip39 seed and bip32 root key, he can withdraw my fund or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

It's unusual, but yes, you can recover the wallet with EITHER the **BIP39 Seed** (hex) or the **BIP32 Root Key** (xprv).  But if your root key starts with `xpub` then it has no private keys so likely won't help.

To do this on Ian's site (in JPG), simply enter the hex BIP39 Seed, or the xprv BIP32 Root Key.  Of course you will need to pick the correct derivation path tab, either BIP44, BIP49 or BIP84.  Assuming your wallet used standard derivations.